# Domain .301 .htaccess redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a domain on Namecheap that I set up to redirect to a url on a different site. The problem is now it redirects everything, including paths that do not exist on the new site.

So old url:

```
domain.tld/bla/bla
```

becomes

```
newdomain.tld/theredirectedurl/bla/bla
```

which throws a 404 error.

My question is basically how to .301 all the incoming links from the old site to the new url:

```
newdomain.tld/theredirectedurl/
```

I tried setting up a refferer redirect but I think because the site goes thru Sucuri firewall that won't work.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://olddomain.tld/[OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.olddomain.tld/ 
RewriteRule .* http://www.newdomain.tld/products/lines/product/ [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to redirect just the domain to new domain or the paths included? Your requirement doesn't seem clear.

Comment: Basically, how do I redirect all the incoming links from the old site to the new url on the new site. Without setting up a simple 301 redirects for all the urls from the old site.

Comment: You would either need to setup domain forwarding from DNS or add the old site as a [site alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias) on the new server. Then you can use `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` to check if it's the old domain and redirect to new.

Comment: The domain is forwarded via DNS at the registrar (Namecheap). The problem is the forwarded links are getting 404 errors because the pages do not exist on the new site. I would like all traffic coming from the old site to forward to a specific page on the new site.

Comment: Then you need to do as mentioned with adding an alias of the old domain to the new server and check the host in the rewrite cond

Answer (score 0):

Close. Use `HTTP_HOST` so it redirects immediately, referer [sic] wouldn't have any affect on first page view, only resources and subsequent clicks.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =olddomain.tld [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.olddomain.tld
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.tld/products/lines/product/ [R=301,L]
```